# PHP 7.2 is_array not eval to true

Tags: php, arrays, variable-types

All, I have a class with some variables defined at the top like so:

```
var $conditionStyle = '';
```

Later I can style one thing like this:

```
$this -> conditionStyle = 'someStyle';
```

Or multiple things like this:

```
$this->conditionStyle[$this->styleRowsCount] = 'someStyle';
```

Next I would see if conditionStyle was an array or not like so:

```
if(is_array($this-> conditionStyle) {...}
```

In php 7.0 and earlier this evaluated fine. With 7.2 I have to use `settype()` or it fails to evaluate correctly. Is this an issue with 7.2 or did 7.2 correct a deficiency in the previous versions?

Comment: You initialise `$conditionStyle` to be a string, but then try to treat it as an array. That will not work. Why can the variable not always be an array? And this doesn't work in 5.6, 7.0, 7.1 or 7.2.

Comment: @fubar It absolutely does work, just in the usual quirky PHP way.

Comment: @bishop, I stand corrected for the tests in 5.6 - 7.0. They did actually work. However in 7.1+ it doesn't work and throws a fatal exception: https://3v4l.org/JRLCS

Comment: @fubar Yes, that does explicitly throw an exception per PHP 7.1 release notes: array append on a string = boom. But what does work... and this is the quirky part... is array assign to a string by index.The OP is doing the latter I suppose, otherwise the OP would have encountered the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP 7.1 changed the behavior of this code:

```
$x = '';
$x[3] = 'foo';
```

In < 7.1, `$x` is:

```
array (
   3 => 'foo',
)
```

while in >= 7.1, it's:

```
string '   f'
```

[See it online at 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/DfQsu)

This change is *poorly* mentioned in the [PHP 7.1 Release Notes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.empty-string-index-operator):

> **The empty index operator is not supported for strings anymore**
>   Applying the empty index operator to a string (e.g. $str[] = $x) throws a fatal error instead of converting silently to array.

The PR that made this change also had the side effects you are noticing, and as [someone else commented](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#120845) in the Notes section of that page.

You should initialize your variable to an array at the outset to work in all versions.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I saw when using 7.2. I simply added settype() before attempting to use the variable as an array.

Comment: @JasonPate Sure, that's a great use of `settype`. You could also cast to an array with `(array)`. But, please consider that your future self or subsequent maintainers may appreciate nornalizing the type to array on the outset.

Comment: Good explanation.